# What is mistake is this Fibonacci series in python?

Tags: python, fibonacci

I want to generate Fibonacci using this code in blow but somehow I couldn't get results printed

```
x=0
y=1
n = int(input("Enter the terms:")) for i in range (n,+1):
  z=x+y
  print(x)
  x=y
  y=z
```

Comment: This is far from valid Python code.

Comment: Not a valid python code.

Comment: What is `range (n,+)` supposed to do?

Comment: Here you can find different approaches to code fibunacci in python [fibunacci](https://www.educba.com/fibonacci-series-in-python/). You can do it interatively or recurively or even with generator.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
x=0
y=1
n = int(input("Enter a number:"))
print(y)
for i in range(n):
    temp = x+y
    x=y
    y=temp
    print(temp)
```

I didn't really get your code... `range(n,+)` what do you want to achieve?

Comment: maybe they want to achieve a fibonacci sequence...

Comment: @diggusbickus if so I think Skywalker can tell me himself/herself, thanks

Comment: Thanks,helpneeded  for solving my mistake in code

Comment: You're welcome, if thats all you needed it would be nice if you could accept the answer :)